# How to modify SELECT statement output in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Basically, the problem is I have a SELECT statement like so:

> SELECT sys_connect_by_path(name, '/')

Which gives me output like this:

> /Name of Folder I want/Another folder...../Folder I'm looking from

And I would like to cut everything out and just have the first folder's name. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT substr(str, instr(str, '/', -1) + 1)
  FROM (
    SELECT '/Name of Folder I want/Another folder...../Folder Im looking from' AS str FROM dual
  )
;
```

The "-1" parameter of *instr* tells Oracle to return first occurrence of the '/' character starting from the end.

Edit: I'm sorry, I read it wrong, another proposal (ugly one):

```
SELECT substr(str, 2, CASE
                        WHEN instr(str, '/', 2, 1) > 0 THEN instr(str, '/', 2, 1) - 2
                        ELSE length(str) - 1
                      END)
  FROM (
    SELECT '/Name of Folder I want/Another folder...../Folder Im looking from' AS str FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '/Name of Folder I want' AS str FROM dual
  )
;
```

Regular expression give another possible solution, though the '/' character must by concatenated to the end for the string we are working on:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(str || '/', '/(.*?)/', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
  FROM (
    SELECT '/Name of Folder I want/Another folder...../Folder Im looking from' AS str FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '/Name of Folder I want' AS str FROM dual
  )
;
```

Here we toook advantage of subexpressions - the last parameter of *regexp_substr* tells Oracle to return only the part of the string that is within the first pair of parentheses.

Comment: I'm actually looking to get the first occurrence starting from the beginning. So just the other way around. I want to get  '/Name of Folder I want' then leave off the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a files table that contained a list of unix-like file paths (directories and possibly even files) you can use a query similar to the following to retrieve the results as a file manager display:

```
SELECT f.file_path,
  SUBSTR(f.file_path, 1, INSTR(f.file_path, '/', -2)) AS parent_file_path
  FROM files_tbl f 
  START WITH (f.file_path = '/') -- Start with the root directory path
  CONNECT BY PRIOR f.file_path = SUBSTR(f.file_path, 1, INSTR(f.file_path, '/', -2))
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY parent_file_path ASC NULLS FIRST, f.file_path ASC;
```

This query assumes that directories are terminated/ended with a / in the file_path, and files would not:

```
/
/folder/
/folder/file.log
/folder/subfolder/
/folder/subfolder/example.txt
```